# What is the difference between jQuery off() and unbind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was using jQuery `.bind()` and `.unbind()` to handle an animation event on scroll.

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
  ... code ...
  if(code_was_successful){
    $(window).unbind(e);
  }
});
```

As of 1.7 (I'm using 1.11) we're supposed to use `.on()` and `.off()`, but `.off()` seems to have no support for an event handler unbinding itself. For normal click events and such, I'd have to save the handler to a variable and set up another event handler to unbind it (which defeats the purpose), and for scroll events it's impossible since `.off()` requires a selector to unbind a specific handler, and scroll events can't have one.

What's the modern way to do this?

Comment: When you call .unbind, it calls .off. I don't quite understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Your question seems a bit unclear. The whole point of `.off()` is to _"Remove an event handler."_ That comes straight from jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/). `$(window).off('scroll')`...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'worse'?

Comment: *"it's impossible since .off() requires a selector to unbind a specific handler"* No it doesn't. Also, what is `e` in `$(window).unbind(e);`? If it's the event object, then yes, that's the big difference between `.undbind` and `.off`, at least per documentation. But since `.unbind` really just calls `.off`, you might be able to just pass the event object.

Comment: ^ Though I wouldn't necessarily recommend it since it's not in the official documentation. They might remove this "feature" once `.unbind` is removed (details for `.off`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ad032d3c7df04827989a4187117614c29bf3a4ad/src/event.js#L822).

Comment: Kevin B and Felix King - Totally right. That's what I get for reading docs instead of source code. If you post that as an answer, I'll select that one. Thanks!

Comment: Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What's the modern way to do this?

Use a **named function expression**:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function handler(){
  ... code ...
  if(code_was_successful){
    $(window).off('scroll', handler);
  }
});
```

> .off() requires a selector to unbind a specific handler

No it does not. Just like `.on` doesn't require a selector. You only need the selector if you want to unbind a delegated event handler.

As you can read in the [**documentation of `.off`**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) about the selector argument:

> A selector which should match the one originally passed to .on() when attaching event handlers.

So if you didn't use one in `.on`, you don't use one in `.off`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.on()` and `.off()` like so:

```
function scrollHandler(e){
    if (myCondition) $(e.target).off('scroll', scrollHandler);
}

$(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

Comment: I believe the second optional argument of [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the selector followed by the handler. I don't believe the above syntax is valid...

Comment: @War10ck: Nope, it's valid. Since it's optional, you can simply omit it. It's the same for `.on`: `.on('click', func)` and `.on('click', 'span', func)` (and they even mean different things).

Answer (score 2):

Using `off` is the modern way, `unbind` is the old way. Use `off`.

See [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

> As of jQuery 3.0, .unbind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .off() method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.