# Remove class from td when the same class is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of `<td>`'s that have the class `clickable`

How can I remove the class clickable to no longer make them clickable? Here's what I have but it doesn't remove the class:

```
    $('td.clickable').click(function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('clickable');
});
```

Comment: `$(this).unbind()` http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: `off()` would be better. `unbind()` has been obsolete for some time and is deprecated in v3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have will certainly remove the class, however it doesn't remove the click event.

I'd suggest modifying your click event to use event delegation, like so:

```
$('table').on("click", ".clickable", function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('clickable');
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/c6eda0kj/

---

**Why event delegation is important:**

Doing something like `$('.clickable').click( ... )` creates a listener for every instance of `clickable`. If there are 100 `.clickable` td's, that's 100 listeners that you've just created. Regardless of whether or not you remove the class from those 100 elements, the event is already attached. In order to remove the event, you'll have to use `unbind` or `off`.

If you instead put the listener on the `table` as I have above, you have just *one* single event. When that event fires (the click of the `table`), it checks to see if the clicked element matches the specified selector. By removing the class, it will then no longer trigger the event - no need for unbinding of any sort.

Answer (score 3):

When you select the element, it adds the event. When the event is not removed because you remove the class. You have two options. Remove the click event. Other option is event delegation.

```
$('td.clickable').click(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('clickable').off("click");
});
```

or

```
$("table").on("click", 'td.clickable', function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('clickable');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @isherwood mentioned use `off()` instead of `unbind()`

here's an example:

```js
$('.clickable').click(function(){ 
  console.log($(this).text());
  $(this).off();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clickable">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td class="clickable">Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="clickable">Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="clickable">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td class="clickable">Francisco Chang</td>
    <td class="clickable">Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961409/jquery-off-is-worse-than-unbind

Comment: I advise against this method. You are creating a click event *for every single td element.* Using event delegation, you can have one single event that handles this all on its own, without the need for unbinding anything.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I just made the example as near as possible to the  OP code.